# Reposition page on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using `scrollTo()` for page scrolling. One problem I found is, when I resize browser, page don't scroll again to element I specified, but it stays somewhere in middle, so I have to click 'scroll' button again to align the page. Is there any way to align page when user resize browser.

I tried using this:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    scrollToPosition(section[position]);
}

// position is variable which I declared above this event
```

But this makes scrolling crazy, the page start to move right/left really fast which is not normal. I believe it binds `onresize` event every time I resize browser.

Is there any solution for my problem

EDIT:

This is jsFiddle, but it seems I don't know how to use jsFiddle since nothing works here: http://jsfiddle.net/52eRj/1/

Comment: Jfiddle your question please.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid reruning function everytime the `resize` event is executed by writing code as below. `scrollToPosition` function will be executed every 1 second when scrolling.

```
var last = new Date().getTime();
var interval = 1000; // Set your own time.
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    var curr = new Date().getTime();
    if (curr - last > interval) {
        last = curr;
        scrollToPosition(section[position]);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are calling your `scrollToPosition` function on every resize event, which can be fired 100 times in a normal manual resize.

To avoid this you can use `clearTimeout` like this:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    clearTimeout(resizeId);
    resizeId = setTimeout(doneResizing, 500);
});


function doneResizing() {
    scrollToPosition(section[position]);
}
```

This way the `doneResizing` function would only be called after 500 miliseconds since the window has stopped resizing, avoiding therefore, those tens or hundreds of unnecessary calls.